# 100% loss when trying to ping external IP assigned to PС

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, ping

I have external IP adress given me by my internet provider, for example, ip.ip.ip.ip on PC I'm using right now, however, when I'm trying to ping ip.ip.ip.ip using this PC I have "100% loss". I need it for remote "Wake Up" function.

I'm using Windows 10, "Private network", ZyXEl Keenetic Omni.

TRACERT results
`1    <1 мс    <1 мс    <1 мс  KEENETIC_OMNI [192.168.1.1]
  2     1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  88.200.185.179
  3     1 ms    <1 мс    <1 мс  88.200.185.110
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  88.200.185.21
  5     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  6     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  7     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  8     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  9     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
 10     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
 11     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
 12     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.`

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to ping your external IP while you are behind the router that has this IP?

Comment: I'm trying to ping my PC's ip using this exact same PC. Sorry, I'm not that good at English :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cisco router port forwarding works from outside networks but not from the local network](https://superuser.com/questions/1517344/cisco-router-port-forwarding-works-from-outside-networks-but-not-from-the-local)

Answer (score 1):

From the trace, I can see that the first hop was to IP address `192.168.1.1`
which is surely your router. The next hop was to `88.200.185.179` which is
a Russian address which I assume is in the network of your ISP.

To make such a loop work : `PC -> router -> ISP -> router -> PC`,
you need a router that supports such a loopback connection.
Evidently yours does not support loopback.

You need to make the `ping` from outside your local network, because the router
cannot do it.

Note also that the static IP address given by your ISP is not that of your PC,
but rather of your router.

Comment: IP is dynamic in my case, but idk if it changes something. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your router is configured for NAT, your PC address will be different from the public IP address. In addition, routers usually do not respond to WAN-side pings to avoid IP scanners. If you just enable Ping response on your router, it will be your router responding, not your PC.
You probably do not want to use ping for wake-up. You can configure your router firewall port forwarding to forward some packets from WAN to specific LAN IP address.